# Match top level brackets of file

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the top of brackets of this file I am trying to parse.

e.g.

```
// some other garbage
Package()
{
// ... lots of garbage in here including nested Package() and commented code
}
// some other garbage
```

Here is my attempt, but its randomly cutting off for some reason in the middle.  I have verified with NotePad++ that the top level matches, which means everything else inside matches.

```
import re

f = open('someTextFile.txt', 'r')
contents = f.read()

r = re.compile("Package\(\)\s*{(.+)\s*}")
m = r.search(contents)
inner_str = m.group(1)
print inner_str
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post what happens when you run it please? It just helps understand whats going on quicker. Also, try printing contents and see if its what you expect it to be.

Comment: There is commented code throughout the //... section, so would I need to adjust my regex for this?

Comment: Since python re doesn't have a recursion feature, you can't deal with nested packages with an only one regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [re.DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) (== re.S) flag. Without this flag, `.` does not match newline.

> re.DOTALL
>
> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a
>   newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

```
import re

with open('t.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()

r = re.compile(r"Package\(\)\s*{(.+)\s*}", re.DOTALL)
m = r.search(contents)
inner_str = m.group(1)
print inner_str
```

You can also specify flag as follow. See [Regular expression syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

```
r = re.compile(r"(?s)Package\(\)\s*{(.+)\s*}")
```

**NOTE: not directly related to the question**

- Use `with open(..) as f` instead of `f = open(...) .... f.close()`
- Use raw string (`r'blah'`) when dealing with regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the REGEX string

```
"^\s*Package\(\)\s*{(.+)\s*}\s*$"
```

That should bind your regex to the start and end of file, its quite possible your code is currently ending at the first closing bracket.